# Delay before :hover becomes active

Tags: html, css, hover

I currently have a background video on my title page with 2 divisions on it, each covering half a page. Both divisions have a message on them, that appears 6 seconds after loading page and also a :hover effect that adds a dark transparent background on whole division.

Now to my question:
I want to know if it's possible to make that :hover take effect 6 seconds after loading page as message appears. Currently :hover darkens half of screen before message appears so it looks kind of stupid for first 6 seconds.

Simplified version of my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="ex1">
    <div class="ex2">
        <h1> Hello World! </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ex3">
        <h1> PFUDOR </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadein 2s forwards;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}

.ex1 {
    height: 300px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-image: url('http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qRC4Vk6kisY/maxresdefault.jpg');
}

.ex2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.ex3 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}

.ex2:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.ex3:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an overlay by using the `:after` pseudo selector and animate it with the same delay. Ex1 does need something like `position: relative` though to make sure the absolute positioned element understands the parents size.

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadein 2s forwards;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}

.ex1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-image: url('http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qRC4Vk6kisY/maxresdefault.jpg');
}

.ex2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.ex3 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}

.ex2:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.ex3:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.ex1:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: remove 0s forwards;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes remove {
    from { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    to { width: 0; height: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
    <div class="ex2">
        <h1> Hello World! </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ex3">
        <h1> PFUDOR </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```